# Good profiler for Fortran and MPI

Tags: profiling, fortran, mpi, profiler

Which profiler do you use for Fortran code base with MPI in it? gprof doesn't seem to be working correctly. Sun Studio Analyzer only returns the timings for the C/C++ system calls and none of the fortran functions appear.

Comment: What is wrong with `gprof`? I use it to profile my MPI programs without problems. Did you compile the objects you want to profile with `-pg`?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: `gprof` is OK if your call tree is pretty shallow, and it is blind to time spent in I/O, if you have any. I use [*this method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) which works with GDB in Fortran. I turn off the MPI, do the performance tuning, then turn MPI back on.

Comment: @IRO-bot: I have used gprof correctly, but either the slave and master logs come out incorrectly, or most of the functions which are sometimes very obviously time-consuming do not show up. So I wanted to see if there are other options. Thanks.

Comment: @SergeyK. Thank you for your point. I am actually hoping to know any other possible profilers/techniques which people use and have found reliable, other than gprof and Sun Studio Suite. I hope I am not asking for recommendations but options. If it is opinionated, I hope I can find out for myself. However, I understand that this type of question does have a chance of getting spam. Please feel free to vote for closure, if you think that is appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: @IRO-bot One more thing to add. I have used gprof with C/C++ and MPI earlier and it has worked fine always. I am just not getting correct results with fortran, and wanted to see if there are other options which you guys might have used. Thanks.

Comment: Some tools which are good for profiling MPI codes are listed [in this community wiki answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607750/tools-to-measure-mpi-communication-costs/10608276#10608276)

Comment: @SergeyK. Right, the answers below illustrate your point. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of performance analysis tools specialized for Parallel/MPI Programs, such as:

- [Score-P](http://www.vi-hps.org/projects/score-p/), which works with a number of different Analysis tools, e.g. [Cube](http://www.scalasca.org/software/cube-4.x), [Vampir](http://vampir.eu)
- [HPCToolkit](http://hpctoolkit.org/) uses sampling only, so you do not have to recompile your application
- [Tau](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/home.php)

At first they may not be as simple to use simple to use, but they provide much more help to investigate the performance of parallel applications.

Answer (score 4):

When the questioner says "gprof doesn't seem to be working correctly", perhaps he's referring to the fact that N MPI processes might clobber the gmon.out file.  In that case, the (undocumented) GMON_OUT_PREFIX environment variable might make gprof more useful:

```
$ export GMON_OUT_PREFIX=gmon.out
$ mpiexec -np 4 cpi
```

Answer (score 2):

[Allinea MAP](http://www.allinea.com/products/map) is a profiler that is simple and straightforward but very powerful.

It is designed to show the performance problems in Fortran, C and C++ MPI applications, and requires very little effort to get started and get profiling.

It is graphical, and has an integrated with a source code browser that shows performance against lines of code, and able to analyse bad MPI behaviour, poor work balance or poor vectorization.

I am one of the team behind the product, so am a little biased. It is commercial - there are evaluation licences available from the website.

Answer (score 0):

`gprof` is a good profiler for Fortran and other GNU based compilers.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris he probably read, and his answer is counterargument to SkypeMeSm question because he not provide any details and explanation "why gprof don't work correctly"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Intel Trace analyzer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-trace-analyzer) to profile MPI communication and [Intel VTune](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe) to obtain a profile of single MPI Task. Both software was widely documented on Intel web site.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add two more profilers : (1) **[mpiP](http://mpip.sourceforge.net)** is a lightweight profiler and can produce textual output but measures only MPI functions. (2) **[Scalasca](http://www.scalasca.org)** - this produces a sophisticated output which can point to synchronisation imbalances (late sender / late receiver) also (as opposed to TAU which does not point to synchronisation imbalances).