# How to check difference between parallel and non parallel programming using mpi

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

How to confirm that parallel program written by me using MPI is faster than the program written in non parallel method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`MPI_Wtime()`](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node150.html) to time you program. [Here](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Wtime.html) is an example. Profiling tools may provide you with a more detailed result. Take a loop at this question :  [Good profiler for Fortran and MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191635/good-profiler-for-fortran-and-mpi)